# SOAP response - parsing xml in php, how to access?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap

I have response from webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
              <ns1:H1 xsi:type="ns1:H1">
                     <BOGUS>
                            <time>1411967345</time>
                            <status>1</status>
                            <speed>0</speed>
                     </BOGUS>
                     <BOGUS>
                            <time>1411964888</time>
                            <status>10</status>
                            <speed>0</speed>
                    </BOGUS>
              </ns1:H1>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I access to element **time** or **status** in `BOGUS[0]` or `BOGUS[1]`?
I tried this:

```
  $soap     = simplexml_load_string($str);
  $response = $soap->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('http://tempuri.org/')->H1;
  $time = $response->BOGUS[1]->time;
  echo $time;
```

, but it's not working. Returns: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

tempuri.org is right. I pasted xml response on: xmlgrid.net and got correct tree.

Comment: **http://tempuri.org/** is right? Furthermore you should explain what you mean with _but it's not working_.

Comment: Yes, tempuri.org is right. Code: $time = $response->BOGUS[1]->time; returns:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You should add information regarding your question as edit of your question and not as comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by loops as you are getting array in return

```
foreach ($response as $res)
    {

    $time = $res->BOGUS[1]->time;
    echo $time;

    }
```

Comment: $time = $response->BOGUS[1]->time; ?? Is it correct? So variable $res is unused.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommandate to use Zend Soap Client for PHP. There u can do like this:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client("MyService.wsdl");
$result = $client->yourMethod(<YouParameters ...>);
echo $result->H1->BOGUS[1]->time;
```

See: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.soap.client.html